# Streaming MP3 files with Orchard CMS

Tags: html, web, streaming, mp3, orchardcms

Is it possible to stream short MP3 files in Orchard CMS? I'm trying to prevent (or at least discourage) people from downloading the files... I tried streaming it with the HTML5 audio tag, but it still allows user to save the audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orchard is a content management system, not a streaming server. You could take a look at streaming them using RTMP via amazons S3 and then using a flash player like flowplayer or jwplayer in Orchard to play the files

Or take a look at Orchard.Azure.MediaServices, you can upload audio files to azure and stream them from there. Never looked used it, but it looks pretty cool.

Basically you will need external services in addition to Orchard for this :)